# Swift separated UITableViewDataSource

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, model-view-controller

I had 4 files in my project:

- myTableViewController.swift
- myTableViewDataSource.swift
- myCustomCell.swift
- myCustomCell.xib

Here's what I implemented:

**myTableViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class myTableViewController: UIViewController {

    let cellIdentifier: String = "myCell"// set same id in storyboard as well

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func setup(){

        let myDataSource = myTableViewDataSource.init(str: "init!")
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "myCustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
        tableView.dataSource = myDataSource
    }
```

**myTableViewDataSource.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class myTableViewDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    init(str:String) {
        print(str)
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDataSource
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        print("section")
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("row")
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myCustomCell
        print("where's my cell")
        return cell;
    }
}
```

What I was trying to do is simply making the dataSource another class and assigning it's instance variable to my tableView.

**Update**

According to @Rajan Maheshwari

adding `tableview.reloadData()` at the bottom of `setup()` got the section/row number right,
but still `"where's my cell"` was not printed ... as `cellForRowAtIndexPath` never executed.

What's the possible problem I got here?

Comment: in setup function., just reload the table once again in the last line.May be it work?

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari the printed results get right! but my cell is still not showing up.

Comment: Register your cell in myTableViewDataSource.swift          
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "myCustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell") 
and tell the result.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari not working. It's weird that the required `cellForRowAtIndexPath` not called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your DataModel is local variable. Move it to class level. e.g:

```
class myTableViewController: UIViewController {
  let myDataSource: myTableViewDataSource
...
  func setup() {
    myDataSource =
...
```

This approach called **MVVM** pattern. You can find information about this pattern [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/mvvm/).
Also, your classes should be named in [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) style. So please change `my...` to `My...` .

Comment: Yes. You are right. Making them to class level solved the problem

Comment: works perfect! and yes I named my original class in CamelStyle, thanks for  reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is why: in your UI design file (storyboard or XIB), your table view has an entry dataSource. It defaults to the view controller.

If you want to change it, add your data source class as an object. Drag a connection from outlets.

If you do not do this, it is hard to overwrite this setting.

[image]

Comment: I guess that datasource is changed in viewDidLoad setup function code